# Why is it such a big thing to recover the first stage in a reusable way?

Tags: first-stage, recovery

When I got it right, the big problem to overcome for SpaceX was, to get the right technique to land the first stage properly.

This requires the first stage also to have enough fuel, so it can burn the the delta V away before it touches down.

But wouldn't it be possible to simply land the first stage by using parachutes? (obvisiously not, as people would do it allready)

So why this wouldn't work?

Comment: 1) Parachutes come with a weight disadvantage as well. 2) They add extra equipment / complications / possible points of failure.. 3) Make it harder to control the landing place. 4) Don't give the same ability to reduce the speed of fall to near 0 at touchdown as do the engines with fuel approach. ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: But if the loss of the first stage in every launch is the source of a factor of x100 for the costs, as SpaceX claims, wouldn't be the weight disadvantage of chutes be somewhat afordable in fuel costs, compared to 100 times the costs for jsut loosing the first stage? It seems to me, your arguments are valid, but can't be the full reason.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. Whether to use either extra fuel ***or*** parachutes costs weight, but the fuel approach brings advantages the chutes cannot (accuracy, low landing speed, using existing equipment in the form of the engines..).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm saying that it is considered a big thing that SpaceX started to develop the techniques to land a first stage. And is considered to be so, as it is a lot of research and development to program the software controlling this. while "just plugging" some additional parachutes to the first stage, is probably not that reliable, but if we are talking about it saving costs of an order of magnitude of 2, then your reasons don't seem to be enough for why no one did so before.

Comment: *"but if we are talking about it saving costs of an order of magnitude of 2"* Where do you get that number from? As an aside, you seem to sweep aside the 'other advantages' I outlined, but most of them would result in the complete loss of the entire booster. I.E. it's pointless, and the designers would have realised that without ever having to try it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: SpaceX claimed this them self as the reason for their efforts in multiple interviews. I can look for an example if it is important for you. Well the only point I see that would result in a complete loss is the one with the fall of speed. but there you could easily start a burn with some modules or so that just stabilize the fall with chutes. Note I'm not trying here to prove anything. I know that they had done ti if it would work. But I jsut want to get WHY this definetly wouldn't work.

Comment: @Zaibis: One aspect not mentioned is that SpaceX intends to eventually land large vehicles on Mars, where parachutes would be impractical (due to both the size of the lander and the thinness of the atmosphere).  Recovering their boosters this way gives them practical experience for that eventual goal.  Even NASA's piggybacking on their results because it's useful for a wide variety of interplanetary landers.

Comment: @Zaibis: Also, SpaceX *did* originally try to use parachutes for the Falcon 1 and first couple of Falcon 9s, but they didn't work.  Turns out powered descent and landing was *easier*.